# Change Picker placeholder alignment in React native

Tags: react-native

I tried to change text alignment to right for picker but it seems there is no way to change.

```
<Picker
selectedValue={this.state.language}
style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'flex-end' }} 
onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>this.setState({ language:  itemValue })}>
<Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
<Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
</Picker>
```

I need something like following pic:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can change the width in the style prop for the picker

```
 <Picker
selectedValue={this.state.language}
style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'flex-end', width:'50%' }} 
onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>this.setState({ language:  itemValue })}>
<Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
<Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
</Picker>
```

you change the width size you get the exact width you want